Power supply output flashing
I have a 12V 5A power supply, similar to the one in the image below, used to power an LED strip that uses about 2A. It was working fine for days, but suddenly the LEDs started to flash. I measured the PSU output, confirming 12V and tested it with a smaller LED strip, showing the same problem.
A visual inspection of the capacitors inside the PSU does not show visible problems.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Or should I just buy a new power supply?

What does the manual/ data sheet say a flashing LED means??

@Fred Driving a load (that is a LED lamp and flashes) means the power supply output turns on and off by itself.

Either the PSU is broken and/or it cannot handle the load. LED strips may need to be driven with constant current instead of constant voltage, but we don't know which type of LED strip you have and if that is the correct type of supply for it, and if it got damaged by the load or for other reasons.
